# Sync guest folder to host machine in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I want to sync a folder from my guest system ( which is ubuntu ) to my local system. I tried to share the folder from my host where I created a symlink to the guest folder but the changes doesn't sync to the guest machine.

Answer (score 1):

not sure of this specific issue but I use a program called syncthing to sync up my bashrc file over several computers. It will sync between Linux, Windows and Android maybe even iPhone. I also have a sync set up where my photos on my phone are synced to my other PC's so I end up with backups of all the pictures I take without having to remember to copy a photo after taking it.